# SimpleXMLElement Error

Tags: php, simplexml

When attempting to create a new instance of SimpleXMLElement from a URL, I get the error `Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'`.

Details:

```
$feed_url = 'https://www.ua.edu/news/feed/';
$the_feed = new SimpleXMLElement( $feed_url, LIBXML_NOCDATA, true );
```

When executing the code above, the error appears on both the Stage and Prod environments but not in Dev. I have compared the xml related settings between the Stage and Dev environments and only slight version differences exist (Dev is a SLIGHTLY older version of PHP than Stage/Prod).

```
$feed_url = 'http://hiphopdx.com/rss/news.xml';
$the_feed = new SimpleXMLElement( $feed_url, LIBXML_NOCDATA, true );
```

In Stage (Can't test this part in Prod), I changed the `$feed_url` variable to another feed's URL.  Everything works as expected. A SimpleXMLElement object is created and can be dumped to the screen.

I have no clue how to proceed to correct this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where do you set `$feed_url`? Should the first line be assigning the URL string to `$feed_url` instead of `$the_feed`?

Comment: Try using `file_get_contents($feed_url);` to see if the problem is that you can't access the URL.

Comment: Enable full warnings with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: @Barmar That was a typo.  The first line is assigning it to $feed_url in the code.  I will correct this in my question.  Thanks.

Comment: Check your [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) setting.

Comment: @PatrickQ [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) setting is set to On.

Comment: @Barmar 
`echo file_get_contents($feed_url);`

returns nothing.  So it's not getting the contents of the file.

Comment: then you need to debug what's blocking that. If you have error reporting enabled, you should see a warning.

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /***/***/somefile.php:496 Stack trace: #0 /***/***/somefile.php(496): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('https://www.ua....', 16384, true) #1 /***/***/some_other_file.php(69): CLASSNAME->update_feeds('http://news.eng...') #2 [internal function]: CLASSNAME_ADMIN->update_feeds('') #3 /wp-includes/plugin.php(525): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 /wp-admin/admin.php(168): do_action('admin_init') #5 /wp-admin/edit.php(10): require_once('/www...') #6 {main} thrown in /***/somefile.php on line 496`

Comment: @Barmar That's the error that's thrown.  There are no other warnings shown.  I have errors turned on on the server and in my wp-config.php file.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry to be such a bother and maybe this needs to be another question but where would I start to debug what's blocking it?

Comment: Maybe the feed site is blocking your servers. Or there's a firewall blocking it. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Try contacting the operators of the feed site, they may be able to assist.

Comment: Will do!  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I checked all of the server settings that were referenced in similar questions and they were all properly set.  I never did figure out why it wasn't pulling the XML from the file.  The solution that I ended up using was to use curl to get the XML from the URL and SimpleXMLELEMENT to handle the raw XML.

```
    function produce_XML_object_tree($raw_XML) {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        try {
            $xmlTree = new SimpleXMLElement($raw_XML);
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            // Something went wrong.
            $error_message = 'SimpleXMLElement threw an exception.';
            foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error_line) {
                $error_message .= "\t" . $error_line->message;
            }
            trigger_error($error_message);
            return false;
        }
        return $xmlTree;
    }

    $feed_url = 'http://feed.url';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feed_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $xml = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $the_feed = produce_XML_object_tree($xml)
```